# How do you add a .jar to the class-path in jaspersoft studio?

Tags: reporting, jaspersoft-studio

I need to add commons-lang3 and commons-math3 so that I can generate medians in my report.  I have already downloaded these files, but how do I add them to the classpath so that jaspersoft studio can reference it?

I am using Jaspersoft Studio Professional 5.6.1

I tried going to project explorer and right clicking on the project, but there was no classpath option.

This is not a duplicate of [use external JAR file in jaspersoft studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23863343/use-external-jar-file-in-jaspersoft-studio) because the solution suggested: `right click on project folder > properties > java build path > libraries > add External JARs..` does not appear to be an option to me.

thanks!

Comment: @tobi6 ive looked into it, and i think my problem stems off of that question, though in that question, it is stated that they right click and the option is there, however I do not see the option for java build path.  I've updated the question with more information.

Comment: Have you had a look into Edit / Preferences for this setting?

Comment: ok i found Classpath Variables in preferences, and I have added the .jars..  still, I get the error: org.apache.commons.math3.stat.StatUtils cannot be resolved to a type.  Did I add them to the correct spot?

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this problem for a while and this is what worked for me:

1. Place jar in workspace
2. Right click on project folder > properties > java build path > libraries > add External JARs.
3. On "Outline" tab click on Project root
4. Go to Properties tab and import the class/package you want to use:

[image: Properties tab]

5. I needed to use this class in a parameter, so i created the parameter:

[image]

6. Double click on the parameter to open the Expression Editor. Click Paremeter and choose proper type:

[image]

7. Edit Class field in Parameter properties

[image]

7. Project > Clean ... Project > Build

Answer (score -1):

step 1:
on the right side of top appeare an red icon(Design report)
step 2:
it will be show in left side
step 3:
will be show the Data Adopter, right click on Data Adopter -> select the new data adopter
step 4:
select the Database JDBC Connection and press next
step 5:
write the name of adopter as you want -> select the JDBC driver [mysql(com.mysql.jdbc.Driver)] -> and write the database name in next field after the backslash 
step 6:
select the class path as shown below and click on add button and select jar file.
step 7:
check connection through test and if succefull than press finish.
step 8:
enjoy jaspersoft studio professional.